# Is mesh wifi better than multiple base stations connected by ethernet?

Tags: wireless-networking

My house is somewhat large and also seems to be subject to more interference than I've experienced in the past. As a result, I currently have three base stations broadcasting 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz WiFi (under "foo" and "foo 5Ghz" SSIDs, respectively).

What I've found is that my client devices tend to want to "stick" to a more distant AP longer than they ideally should, resulting in degraded or totally broken WiFi in certain areas of the house.

I've been reading about consumer "mesh" WiFi solutions like Eero, Luma, Amplify, and most recently Netgear's Orbi. They all seem to suggest that they do a better job of eliminating these dead zones.

However before I shell out $400+ for one of them I'm wondering:

1. Do they effectively act like multiple base stations with the same SSID, but instead of connected via Ethernet (like I have today) they use WiFi? If so, I can't imagine that I'd see better performance.
2. Or are they doing something new that would lead to better overall performance in my home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes roaming between APs is controlled by the client so this kind of mesh won't help. Particularly if you have competing neighbouring ssids this will decrease your speeds as the repeaters share the available bandwidth.

Clients will stick to a distant AP even if there is a stronger closer one until the signal drops below a certain point. There are tweaker apps that let you raise this threshold and make it switch sooner, however there is a pause as it switched from one AP to another and a side effect is that you will get these more often when you are on the borderline.

With clients/APs that support 802.11k, 802.11r and 802.11v you can get faster more transparent transitions but these are only supported by newer clients and business grade APs.